# php foreach loop items in equal dates

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have a php foreach loop my code is:

```
<?php 
  foreach($items as $item){
     
    echo $item->date;
    echo $item->title;
   }
?>
```

my out put for example this is:

> 2014-08-23
>
> title1
>
> 2014-08-23
>
> title2
>
> 2014-08-30
>
> title3

but i want echo my item this format:

> 2014-08-23
>
> title1
>
> title2
>
> 2014-08-30
>
> title3

i want echo Equal dates once and show items. how can do it? thank you

Comment: I cannot believe how many people can't figure this out on their own. Set a variable to the last date, and then compare the current date to the variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this

```
$temp = array();
foreach($items as $item){
    if (!in_array($item->date, $temp)){
        $temp[$item->title] = $item->date;
    }
}

foreach($temp as $title=>$date){       
    echo $date.'</br>';
    echo $title.'</br>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$last_date = null;
foreach($items as $item){
    if ($item->date != $last_date) {
        echo $item->date;
        $last_date = $item->date;
    }
    echo $item->title;
}
```